# Filter rows in csv based on condition in nth column

Tags: csv, awk

I am using this cmd to filter csv file. Desired function keep headers + filter True in 19th column.

`awk -F, 'NR==1 || $19 ~ "True"' output.csv > outputX.csv`

The original file has 250 rows when I use this cmd I get 101 rows, but when I open the original file with excel and filter 19th column to "TRUE" I am getting 112 rows (cmd filters to 101 rows).
Opening raw csv shows ,"True", (comma delimiters). Opening get data in excel shows 19th row as "TRUE". Why is excel loading True to TRUE?
I want 112 rows with this cmd and possibly reason why is it different?

Hope it's understandable.
Thanks.

EDIT: [Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TaIAqAfx3TEd1hna_TLJpgquphCmqwFZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [edit] your question to **include** (not **reference**) concise, testable sample input and expected output. And don't use 19+ columns, you can demonstrate your needs for 4 or 5 lines of 4 or 5 columns each. Chances are by creating the [mcve] you'll figure out the problem for yourself and not need to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 19th column has "TRUE" or "True"

If its "True", try this:

```
awk -F, '$19 == "True"{print}' output.csv > outputX.csv
```

Comment: Your command does not work for me...result file is empty. But when I replace == by ~ i'm getting 100 rows (without header).

Comment: Can you show the first few line from your input fie?

Comment: Yes. Later today.

Comment: With the cmd I should be getting header + first two rows but for some reason it filtered out 3107. FIle is in original post.

Comment: head -n 5 output.csv > output_5lines.csv

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really following, but I imagine you want something likethis:

```
$ awk -F, '(FNR==1) || (tolower($19) ~ "true")' input.csv > output.csv
```

This will also match if `$19` contains words like "obs**true**nts". The reason why `tolower($19) == "true"` will not work is because excell probably quotes the word. So this might also work:

```
$ awk -F, '(FNR==1) || (tolower($19) == "\"true\"")' input.csv > output.csv
```